Dynamic Choice Input for GitHub Actions Across Organizations
I have a workflow used across multiple GitHub organizations.
One of the inputs is an AWS account, which means the user can choose which AWS account to perform the actions on.
Right now, it is a simple string input, but I want to convert it to a choice input.
I’d like to present a list of choices without hard-coding them in the workflow file, for aesthetic reasons, of course, but mainly because each organization should use a different list of AWS accounts.
I do not want to multiply the WF for each organization.
Ideally, each organization should manage its own list externally.
The ideal solutions:

Store the AWS accounts list in an Actions environment variable (e.g. AWS_ACCOUNTS ) at the organization level, that way, each organization manages its own environment variable, avoiding changes to the workflow file.

Store the AWS accounts list in some external file and as I said, each organization would be able to manage its own file.


The problem with those approaches- GitHub Actions doesn’t natively support injecting a list variable into a choice input, or injecting the choices from an external file into a choice input.
I would be happy to hear your thoughts, thank you so much in advance.
